# Find arc length of implicit function

Tags: matlab

I want to convert the function

f(x) = x^2 + y^2 -4.5*sin(x*y)-1.

into polar form by x=r*cos(t) and y=r*sin(t). The code for substituting into polar coordinates is

```
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
x=r*cos(t)
y=r*sin(t)
```

My function then becomes

```
f(t)=(r.*cos(t)).^2 + (r.*sin(t)).^2 - 4.5.*sin((r.*cos(t)).*(r.*sin(t))) - 1
```

But now im tasked to solve the radius r in terms of the angle t and then using `fzero` to compute different radiuses for different angles. I can't solve r out of the equation f(t)=0 in terms of elementary equations. How s this done?

Answer (score 0):

First define related syms, then solve using `solve` function:

```
syms r t;
solutions = solve((r*cos(t))^2 + (r*sin(t))^2 - 4.5*sin((r*cos(t))*(r*sin(t))) - 1, r);
```

For this case you do not need dot before operators.

Also, you can simplify it by replacing `(r*cos(t))^2 + (r*sin(t))^2` with `r^2`:

```
solutions = solve(r^2 - 4.5*sin((r*cos(t))*(r*sin(t)), r);
```

Comment: Tanks man! But what are related syms? And why don't I need the dots before the operators?

Comment: @Parseval as I've written `r` and `t`.

Comment: @Parseval it is for symbolic math.

Comment: Now I have this: ´x=r*cos(t);
y=r*sin(t);
syms 'r' 't';
solutions = solve(r^2 - 4.5*sin((r*cos(t))*(r*sin(t))) - 1, 'r');´ But I get error message "Undefined function or variable 'r'.".

Comment: My solution is based on symbolic math. So, you don't need to any numeric value. just run the written two lines in the solution.

Comment: Get the following: "Warning: Do not specify equations and variables as character vectors. Instead, create symbolic variables with syms. 
Warning: Unable to find explicit solution. For options, see help. "

Comment: only problem with this is that I'm supposed to use fzero to solve r.